# Jenkins: unable to access the artifacts on the initial run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My setup: main node runs on Linux and an agent on Windows. I want to compile a library on an agent, archive those artifacts and copy them on the main node to create a release togather with the Linux compiled binaries.

This is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```java
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build-Windows') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    filename 'docker/Dockerfile-Windows'
                    label 'windows'
                }
            }
            steps {
                bat "tools/ci/build.bat"
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build_32/bin/mylib.dll'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            node('linux') {
                copyArtifacts filter: 'build_32/bin/mylib.dll', flatten: true, projectName: '${JOB_NAME}', target: 'Win32'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I run this project for the first time, I get the following error

`Unable to find project for artifact copy: mylib`

But when I comment the `copyArtifacts` block and rerun the project, it is successful and I have artifacts vivible in the project overview. After this I can reenable the `copyArtifacts` and then the artifacts will be copied as expected.

How to configure the pipeline so it can access the artifacts on the initial run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `copyArtifacts` capability is usually used to copy artifacts between different builds and not between agents on the same build. Instead, to achieve what you want you can use the [stash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) and [unstash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstash-restore-files-previously-stashed) keywords which are designed exactly for passing artifacts from different agents in the same pipeline execution:

> **stash**: Stash some files to be used later in the build.
> Saves a set of files for later use on any node/workspace in the same Pipeline run. By default, stashed files are discarded at the end of a pipeline run

> **unstash**: Restore files previously stashed.
> Restores a set of files previously stashed into the current workspace.

In your case it can look like:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build-Windows') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    filename 'docker/Dockerfile-Windows'
                    label 'windows'
                }
            }
            steps {
                bat "tools/ci/build.bat"
                // dir is used to control the path structure of the stashed artifact
                dir('build_32/bin'){
                    stash name: "build_artifact" ,includes: 'mylib.dll'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            node('linux') {
                // dir is used to control the output location of the unstash keyword
                dir('Win32'){
                   unstash "build_artifact"
            }
        }
    }
}
```